# Counting first appearance of a field in a CSV file

Tags: python, dictionary

Using the format of following CSV file:

```
Pos   ID    Name
1   0001L01 50293
2   0002L01 128864
3   0003L01 172937
4   0004L01 12878
5   0005L01 demo
6   0004L01 12878
7   0004L01 12878
8   0005L01 demo
```

I want to include in a dictionary: `[ID], {Pos, Name, FirstTime`} where `FirstTime` corresponds with the position that an `ID` first appears in the CSV file. For instance `ID = 0005L01` would have: `[0005L01],{5,demo,5},{8,demo,5}`

I have managed to store `[ID], {Pos,Name}` but I am struggling with `FirstTime`. So far I've got:

```
 # From the csv reader, save it to a list
 dlist=[]
 for row in reader:
      # store only the non empty lines
      if any(row):
         dlist.append(row)
d={}
for row in dlist:
    d.setdefault(row[1],[]).append([row[0],row[2]])
```

Comment: @thefourtheye `FirstTime` is the the position that an ID first appears in the CSV file

Comment: You really want `{Pos, Name, FirstTime}` to be a set, rather than something ordered, like a tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's easier if you compute `firstTime` first, and then you fill your dictionary:

```
# From the csv reader, save it to a list
dlist=[]
for row in reader:
    # store only the non empty lines
    if any(row):
        dlist.append(row)
firstTime={}
for row in dlist:
    if row[1] not in firstTime: firstTime[row[1]] = row[0]
d={}
for row in dlist:
    d.setdefault(row[1],[]).append([row[0],row[2],firstTime[row[1]]])
```

Comment: @ mescalinum: Almost got it, just replace  `if row[0] not in firstTime: firstTime[row[1]] = row[0]` by  `if row[1] not in firstTime: firstTime[row[1]] = row[0]`

Comment: OH! right! sorry I thought this solution was simple enough that I did not test it :-) [I just corrected my answer]

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay to use Pandas, try this:

```
In [269]: temp
Out[269]: 
   Pos       ID    Name
0    1  0001L01   50293
1    2  0002L01  128864
2    3  0003L01  172937
3    4  0004L01   12878
4    5  0005L01    demo
5    6  0004L01   12878
6    7  0004L01   12878
7    8  0005L01    demo
```

Next, group by ID and apply `min`:

```
In [271]: temp.groupby('ID').min().rename(columns={'Pos':'Firsttime'})
Out[271]: 
         Firsttime    Name
ID                        
0001L01          1   50293
0002L01          2  128864
0003L01          3  172937
0004L01          4   12878
0005L01          5    demo

In [272]: y = temp.groupby('ID').min().rename(columns={'Pos':'Firsttime'})
```

Now, merge with the original dataframe:

```
In [276]: temp.merge(y)
Out[276]: 
   Pos       ID    Name  Firsttime
0    1  0001L01   50293          1
1    2  0002L01  128864          2
2    3  0003L01  172937          3
3    4  0004L01   12878          4
4    6  0004L01   12878          4
5    7  0004L01   12878          4
6    5  0005L01    demo          5
7    8  0005L01    demo          5
```

Now, iterate and save it into the dictionary:

```
In [280]: temp.merge(y).iterrows().next()
Out[280]: 
(0, Pos                1
 ID           0001L01
 Name           50293
 Firsttime          1
 Name: 0, dtype: object)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
first = {}

for row in reader:
    if any(row):
        pos, ID, name = row
        if ID not in first:
            first[ID] = pos
        d[ID].append(pos, name, first[ID])
```